# PHP export to excel using eexcelview

Tags: php, yii, phpexcel, yii-extensions

Hi I'm trying to get data in excel with [eexcelview](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eexcelview/) . I have added the code in controller

```
$query = " some query from 4 tables ";
$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($query, array(
    'sort'=>array('attributes'=>array(
                                    'col1', 
                                    'col2',
                                    'col3', 
                                    'col4',
                                    'col5'  ),),));
$this->widget('application.extensions.EExcelView', array(
        'dataProvider'=> $dataprovider,
        'title'=>'Title',
        'autoWidth'=>false,
         ));
```

My understanding is when this action is called, it will directly ask me to save excel report. But instead I'm getting error `The "dataProvider" property cannot be empty.`,

```
C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\zii\widgets\CBaseListView.php(106)
100      * Initializes the view.
101      * This method will initialize required property values and instantiate {@link columns} objects.
102      */
103     public function init()
104     {
105         if($this->dataProvider===null)
106             throw new CException(Yii::t('zii','The "dataProvider" property cannot be empty.'));
```

Also, same `$dataprovider` in `CGridView` works fine.

What is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP variables are case sensitive. So you must change your code to

```
$this->widget('application.extensions.EExcelView', array(
        'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
        'title'=>'Title',
        'autoWidth'=>false,
         ));
```

Comment: Thanks for sorting it out.